# Comparing two elements to set the current node in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt so please forgive if this is a naive question. I need to match the value of an element containing a department name in the source document to the value of a child element in another document that lists variations on that department name as children, and set that child's parent as the current node to get the value of the other children.

Here is an example of the the Source Document:

```
<sourceRoot>
 <sourceElement>foo</sourceElement>
</sourceRoot>
```

Here is an example of the the List Document:

```
<departments>
 <department>
  <child1>bar</child1>
  <child2>bar2</child2>
  <child3>bar3</child3>
 </department>
 <department>
  <child1>baz</child1>
  <child2>baz2</child2>
  <child3>baz3</child3>
 </department>
 <department>
  <child1>foo</child1>
  <child2>foo2</child2>
  <child3>foo3</child3>
 </department>
</departments>
etc.
```

This is the desired result:

```
<child2value>foo2</child2value>
<child3value>foo3</child3value>
```

I have attempted using this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="departments" select="document('dept.xml')/departments"/>  

    <xsl:template match="/">          
        <xsl:variable name="sourceElement" select="sourceRoot/sourceElement"/>                   
        <xsl:variable name="child1" select="$departments/department/child1"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="child2" select="$departments/department/child2"/>
        <xsl:variable name="child3" select="$departments/department/child3"/>

        <xsl:choose>    
        <xsl:when test="$sourceElement=$child1">               
            <child2value>
                <xsl:value-of select="$departments/department[.]/child2"/>
            </child2value>
            <child3value>
                <xsl:value-of select="$departments/department[.]/child3"/>                
            </child3value>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it returns the child values for all the `department` nodes.

```
<child2value>bar2 baz2 foo2</child2value>
<child3value>bar3 baz3 foo3</child3value>
```

I know I am missing a key concept here on how to set a node as current. Thanks for any advice for this newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you want can be selected by a single XPath expression, as demonstrated with this transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="sourceElement">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/dept.xml')
               /*/*[child1 = current()]
                     /*[not(self::child1)]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<sourceRoot>
 <sourceElement>foo</sourceElement>
</sourceRoot>
```

**and the second provided XML document resides in the local file system at `c:\temp\delete\dept.xml`:**

```
<departments>
 <department>
  <child1>bar</child1>
  <child2>bar2</child2>
  <child3>bar3</child3>
 </department>
 <department>
  <child1>baz</child1>
  <child2>baz2</child2>
  <child3>baz3</child3>
 </department>
 <department>
  <child1>foo</child1>
  <child2>foo2</child2>
  <child3>foo3</child3>
 </department>
</departments>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<child2>foo2</child2>
<child3>foo3</child3>
```

**Update**:

**If we want to change the names of the selected elements above, this is really simple:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="sourceElement">
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/dept.xml')
               /*/*[child1 = current()]
                     /*[not(self::child1)]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'child')]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}value"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces**:

```
<child2value>foo2</child2value>
<child3value>foo3</child3value>
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight into XPath. I was able to get exactly the result needed. Here are snippets of the actual documents to illustrate how your lesson in theory was put into practice:

Comment: Sorry, my edited comments timed out.  I was able to get exactly the result needed into an element within a larger template. Below is the actual xsl. `sourceElement` is `DISS_inst_contact`; `child 1` is `proquest`; `child 3` is `heading`. (`child2` was used in another element.)  `<xsl:for-each select="DISS_description/DISS_institution/DISS_inst_contact">`  `<xsl:value-of select="document('dept.xml')/*/*[proquest = current()]/*[(self::heading)]"/>`   
`</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 0):

I would solve that as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:param name="dep-url" as="xs:string" select="'test2013033102.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="dep-doc" as="document-node()" select="doc($dep-url)"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="by-child" match="department" use="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="source" as="element(sourceElement)*" select="sourceRoot/sourceElement"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by-child', $source, $dep-doc)/*[not(. = $source)]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="department/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}value">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms your input into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<child2value>foo2</child2value>
<child3value>foo3</child3value>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was unable to get a successful result even when `test2013033102.xml` was cahnged to the name of the list document. Saxon-PE 9.4.0.4 gave this error message: Severity: fatal. Description: An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of parameter $dep-url. I appreciate the reply though.